# Prove if $a>1, r,s\in \mathbb{Q}, r>s>0$ , then $a^r>a^s>1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have proven that if $a>1$ and $m>n$, then $a^m>a^n>1$ with $m,n \in\mathbb{N}$

But I am having severe problems when I am trying to prove it for  $a>1, r,s\in \mathbb{Q}, r>s>0$ , then $a^r>a^s>1$...

Any impulses, suggestions?

Comment: Do you know that $(a^{p/q})^q=a^p$, for $p,q\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: I do. Should I set $r=m/n$ and $s=o/p$ with $m,o\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n,p \in \mathbb{N}$? then $m/n > o/p$  .... ..... ....

Comment: Actually, we should also have $m,o\in\Bbb N.$ Do you see why? But to continue your thought, note that $$\frac{m}{n}>\frac{o}{p}$$ if and only if $$mp>no$$ if and only if $$mp=no+k$$ for some $k\in\Bbb N.$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: But isn't $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{n}{m}.n\in \mathbb{Z},m\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: @Analysis: Yes, but since the rational numbers we're dealing are strictly positive, both the numerator and denominator must be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r=m/n>p/q=s$, then $mq>np$ with $mq,np\in\mathbb{N}$. You have proved $b^{mq}>b^{np}>1$ for $b>1$. Let $a>1$. Choose $b=a^{1/nq}>1$, what do you get?

Comment: Why $$b=a^{1/nq}>1$$?  Why $nq$?

Comment: If $b\leq 1$, then $a=b^{nq}\leq 1^{nq}=1$ a contradiction, so $b>1$. Why $nq$? Well, just plug in this value of $b$ in the inequality and you'll see why.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.